# Using wshShell with ActiveXObject in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, activexobject

I see a lot of post but I find myself very confused. I know NOTHING about ActiveX but have managed to get the below to work but only when manually changing the security setting in IE. With the given code, what is the best method for implementation? Is there a script available that would change the IE settings on all users? This is strictly for use on the company intranet.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Image Viewer</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
 APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
 BORDER="no"
 CAPTION="no"
 SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 SYSMENU="yes"
 SCROLL="no"
 WINDOWSTATE="normal">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function RunFile() 
{
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("C:/PATH/ViewImageForm.exe", 1, false);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="RunFile();">

HTML Design code:
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: "With the given code, what is the best method for implementation?" Don't implement it. ActiveX is terrible.

Comment: @bjb568 well the aspx page hits a winform to use a vendor supplied viewer that is needed on a specific setup for our systems.

Comment: @bjb568 this is all internal, everyone uses IE and in a VERY controlled environment. do you know anything about OCX files?